# How to hide controller and method name,while working with Jquery ajax in Php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

I am developing project using codeigniter framework in that I have created file `script.php` and load like this

```
$this->load->view('users_list');  //view file
$this->load->view('script');      // contain jquery ajax scripts
```

So all jquery ajax have written in `script.php` file, when I click on 'Get User' button it will call `jquery` `ajax` method and get data,

it's fine  but if we inspect  element (ctrl+shift+i) or in console window anyone can see name of controller,method  and even data which is get in response so from security concern it is not good as controller, method name is visible to anyone.

so how to hide this, because most of the sites hide this like `facebook` and no one aware which method/function they are calling.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="get_allusers" value="Get Users"/>
```

script to call method

```
<script>

$(".get_allusers").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url('Users/users_list') ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { },
           success: function (response) {
alert(response);
 },
        error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });

});

</script>
```

Method in controller

```
public function users_list(){

    $result=$this->db->get('users')->result();
    foreach($result as $users_details){
        echo $users_details->id.$users_details->name."<br>";

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to do what you ask. To be able to call an endpoint it has to be accessible publicly. If you want to add security then you could look in to using some kind of token/authentication system to verify the location the calls are coming from, but the URLs themselves will still be public

Comment: Yes, you can still easily see it, either through following the call stack of the code or, even simpler, watching the network traffic in the console.

Comment: You can encrypt your data which you are passing ajax and also response of ajax but  can't hide you controller and method name

Comment: The question is: WHY do you need to hide / obfuscate this information? This is the way things work, even for high-value / sophisticated sites....

Comment: Out of curiosity: who cares what the controller / method names are? You can make them meaningless, if it's that important to you.... `ajax/route1` for example....

Comment: @MayankVadiya true except that if you're using JS to encrypt the data (which you'd have to), then anyone looking at the page can watch the data before it gets encrypted...so what's the point?

Comment: I agree with the other comments above...why do you think you need to do this? At best all you can do is obfuscate things by using meaningless names and minified code, but in the end you can't actually hide any of your data or your URLs. Even if you make it hard to figure out what the URLs are for, someone determined enough will work it out in the end. It sounds like maybe you are following the (very discredited) logic of "security by obscurity". It is always fallible in the end.

Comment: Instead of being afraid that people will discover your URLs, the correct solution is to ensure that the URLs have got the correct security protection. In other words, if someone makes a request to a particular URL, you only respond to the request if the requesting user is allowed to do so, according to your application's rules. Ensure you _authenticate_ all requests, and that you also _authorise_ them (i.e. you apply rules to ensure the specific user can only access data or perform commands that they have permissions for). If the request doesn't pass the validation, you reject the request.

Comment: That way, if your application is properly screening all requests, then malicious agents can make as many requests to your URLs as they like, and they still won't be able to do anything they shouldn't. (And of course if making too many requests is in itself a problem (i.e. DDOS attacks) then you can build in more monitoring to ensure you block users/IP addresses who are repeatedly spamming you with bad requests). That's how you secure a web app -  not by attempting to hide the fact that bits of it exist.

Comment: P.S. It's perhaps important to note that the advice above applies to all your application's URLs, not just ones that are called via AJAX. After all, the ones called directly in the browser, to render your main views, are even more visible that ones that are used only by AJAX calls. They need to be secure as well.